# Automatically changing the angle of a symbol in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector, symbology, fields-attributes

I am working with an iron age cemetery in QGIS. I marked every grave in a point layer with several columns; amongst others, burial rite (inhumation, cremation etc.). I inserted a second column for the orientation of the inhumations. I categorized the vector symbols according to the burial rite column and created one simple vector symbol for the inhumations, now I would like it to rotate automatically according to the orientation column.

Is that possible using one layer, or do I have to put all the inhumations in a second layer.

Comment: Should be possible with one layer. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60119/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a data-defined override using the button right next to the angle input

[image]

In previous QGIS versions, this functionality was available through the data-defined properties button.

Comment: That seems to be my solution. But I dont have the button you have clicked at on your screenshot. I use QGIS 2.8.1 is there a plugin I have to install for the override?

Comment: It has to be there in 2.8.1. Make sure you selected the "Simple marker" entry in the symbol layer list and that the whole dialog is visible.

Comment: Ok. That is the solution! For anyone who has the same problem: You need to work with QGIS 2.8.1 - it is a new feature not available in earlier versions.